# Does aircrack-ng use GPU/CUDA capabilities?

Tags: password-cracking, kali-linux, aircrack-ng, hashcat, gpu

As stated, does aircrack-ng when brute forcing a WPA2 handshake capture use GPU/CUDA resources such as a program like Hashcat does?

Comment: I think hashcat supports gpu based wpa2 cracking.

Comment: Hashcat does, yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so. There's [only one mention of OpenCL or CUDA in the source code](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/blob/e63ce86096b980c34f2d85a43bb9c73171213bc1/src/wpapsk.c#L400), and it appears to be a leftover from code copied from John the Ripper.

Edited to answer your implicit question: if you want efficient WPA2 cracking on GPU, consider [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) for the cracking, and [hcxtools](https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools) for conversion to the required format ([hccapx](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-6273.html)). hashcat is superior to some other implementations because it has a rules engine that is implemented directly in-kernel on GPU.

Answer (score 9):

As stated by @RoyceWilliams, it does not seem to use CUDA. For this purpose, you might want to look at [Pyrit](https://github.com/JPaulMora/Pyrit), since it leverages CPUs and GPUs on the cracking process.

NB: I wanted to leave this as a comment but I still don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Here, have some rep. +1

Comment: Note that if both GPU and CPU are present, hashcat will only use GPU by default - but you can explicitly ask hashcat to use both CPU and GPU if desired.

Comment: Hi, Pyrit worked with CPU and GPU in my case, (using Ubuntu 18.10) it was difficult to install but it ended up working.

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a CUDA version of aircrack-ng but since oclhashcat became popular, you will need to build from the source to enable the CUDA feature in aircrack-ng. There is little documentation about how to enable it however.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have enough "reputation" I cannot comment, but as Aero Wang's answer, you need to download cuda lib and recompile aircrack, I did this many years ago trying on a Nvidia Quattro, the aircrack-ng cuda runs very fast, if I remember well I could get 30000 passwords/sec instead of 5000/sec on a Xeon.
But lately I try hashcat and it is better as built-in support for GPU is included, you don't need to recompile.